# Cambio formato de fecha en Django

Tags: django

Necesito usar este formato de fecha `'%d/%m/%Y'`
el campo en el modelo:

```
f_entrega =models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
```

Me da el siguiente error.
`“15-09-2020”` value has an invalid date format. It must be in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

en el `settings.py`

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Santiago'

USE_I18N = False

USE_L10N = False

DATE_FORMAT = ['%d-%m-%Y']

#DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d-%m-%Y']

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d-%m-%Y']

USE_TZ = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente no pude cambiar el formato.

Tuve que tomar la fecha desde el form (en el formato que yo quería DD-MM-YYYY), transformarla y pasarla al modelo en el formato YYYY-MM-DD.

```
                ...
            fecha_entrega = datetime.strptime(i['f_entrega'], '%d-%m-%Y')  # desde form
            item.f_entrega = datetime.strftime(fecha_entrega, '%Y-%m-%d')  # trasformar
            ...
            item.save()
```